# Why is a projective subspace itself a projective variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let K^(n+1) be a vector space and W be its subspace.

Then projective subspace P(W) is said to be a projective variety of P(K^(n+1)).
Could anyone tell me why it is so?

Answer (score 1):

A line in $W$ is a line in $K^{n+1}$ by the inclusion $W\to K^{n+1}$; this realises $P(W)$ as a subset of $P(K^{n+1})$.

To see that this subset is algebraic, interpret a linear equation defining $W$ in $K^{n+1}$ (which is homogeneous of degree $1$) as an equation in the homogeneous coordinates on $P(K^{n+1})$.

Comment: I can see that W can be written as linear combinations of its basis elemenets, but how to express W by some 'equations'?

Comment: Pick a basis $w_1,\dotsc,w_n$ of $W$ and extend it to a basis $w_1,\dotsc,w_{n+1}$ of $K^{n+1}$. Let $\lambda_1,\dotsc,\lambda_{n+1}$ be the corresponding coordinate functions; then in these coordinates the equation of $W$ is $\lambda_{n+1}=0$. You can then change coordinates into something else, like the standard basis of $K^{n+1}$, if you like.